# Can't Compile Hello World in Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

when I compile this program in Netbeans, the program shows the text in the output- What is it I'm doing wrong that causes this error and how do I fix it?

This is the Code I'm using:

```
/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: Oliver
 *
 * Created on May 4, 2014, 12:33 AM
 */
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

This is the results...:

```
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/sers/Oliver/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Learning'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/learning.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/sers/Oliver/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Learning'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
make.exe[2]: mkdir: Command not found
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 127
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/sers/Oliver/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Learning'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/sers/Oliver/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Learning'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

Comment: This line: `mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows` is failing. Make sure the mkdir command is accessible directly from console under the current user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into your `/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/` for `mkdir.exe` .

if you found it there, you have not set your `path environment variable` to that folder.

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;
```

So add it at the first place.

I apologize for the somewhat atypical picture. Binn currently working on a win2000 computer and can not switch.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this is not enough, you can set manually "make.exe" into the C/C++ NetBeans Properties > Make Command textbox.

It's located in the path said in the previous answer.

C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe